# Prompting for file download C backend

Tags: javascript, html, c, fpga

I have an FPGA that is hosting a website with an html and javascript front end and a C backend (ugh).

Is there anyway to send a file from the C backend to the client?  I'm talking to the backend via an html form (since the back end is hosted on an FPGA I'm unsure how it will handle AJAX).

Some tricky points, the website is hosted in read only memory (hence the desire to send the client a file).

I'm going nuts, is this impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by "is hosted on an FPGA"?  Presumably your FPGA is emulating some CPU, e.g. an ARM?

Comment: The code on the FPGA implements (though not fully) http, and the file structure for the website is stored in the FPGAs flash memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is possible.  You just need to ensure the relevant HTTP headers are set in the `GET` response.  Specifically `Content-type` and `Content-Disposition`.  e.g.:

```
Content-type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible via CGI, see for example: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html